# How to Travis CI and Jupyter Notebooks through Nbsphinx

Tags: python, travis-ci, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I'm trying to work with nbsphinx and travis in a github repository along with Jupyter notebooks.

Repository setup:

```
.
├── _docs
|   ├── config.py # I added nbsphinx extension here
|   ├── including.rst # File with .. include :: ../projects/testingjupyter.ipynb
|   └── index.rst # basically just toctree with "including" among other titles
├── _projects
|   └── testingjupyter.ipynb
├── tests
├── travis.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

travis.yml:

```
language: python
python:
     - "2.7.12"
     - "3.5"
     - "3.5"
     - "nightly"

install: 
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - sudo apt-get install pandoc

script:
    - py.test tests/
    - travis-sphinx --source ./docs build

after_success:
    - travis-sphinx --branches=master,Develop deploy
```

requirements.txt:

```
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.2.4
Sphinx==1.5.3
travis-sphinx==1.4.3
flask==0.12
jupyter
nbconvert
pandoc
nbsphinx
IPython
ipykernel
```

When travis-sphinx tries to build, it appears the following error: Unexpected indentation

[image: Travis Log]

testingjupyter.ipynb :

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Testing Jupyter"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {
    "collapsed": false
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Hello World\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print('Hello World')"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.5.1"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Comment: Show us the contens of `testingjupyter.ipynb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work with

```
.. include:: ../projects/testingjupyter.ipynb
```

AFAIK, this only works with `*.rst` files (see [docutils docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include)).

You should add your notebooks to the `toctree`, e.g.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 3

    testingjupyter
```

Specifying the `.ipynb` extension is optional.

Alternatively, you can include it in another notebook with [nbsphinx-toctree](http://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subdir/toctree.html) metadata.

**UPDATE:**

The notebook indeed has to be in the source directory. Using notebooks from outside of the source directory is not supported, though it was proposed in https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/pull/33.

Comment: The main problem here is including `.ipynb` files inside a directory different from the docs one.

Comment: @EzequielCastaño Did you manage to correctly `include` a notebook that's in the source directory? I'm getting the same kind of errors as the OP.

Comment: I've tried to `include` the notebook file in the source directory and neither using `toctree` nor the including file with the `..include:` worked. Same error

Comment: @EzequielCastaño It looks like the error is caused by the now obsolete file `including.rst`, which Sphinx is still trying to convert (and failing, as before). It works fine when you remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much, after your PR it worked perfectly, just the day after the iPython updated from 5.x to 6.0 so I had to change the requirements file to preserve compatibility with Python 2.7